# Would it be handy to have a live activity tracker for moderation purposes?

Tags: feature-request, moderation, recent-activity, tracking

Would it be handy for high reputation users to have a live activity tracker available for moderation purposes? Not a tracker that solely tracks a tag or a question but a tracker that covers all activity. As this would be locked to high reputation users only there shouldn't really be a scalability issue...

Example events, which could be put in a one box style:

- Person 1 asked question V.
- A close vote has been cast on question W.
- Person 3 started a bounty on question X.
- Favorite A received a new answer.
- Person 4 has commented on answer B of Favorite C.
- Person 5 asked a question on meta.
- Person 6 has edited question Y.
- Person 7 has rolled back question Z.

This would naturally result in more smooth moderation, as we would be on top of the events rather than that they are hidden away in a summary in the tools section or by manually tracking questions. The above events are just merely examples, some events like roll backs might not actually benefit us and there might be other events out there that really do benefit us when moderating.

Of course this is just an idea, so I'm looking for thoughts about this and if it's good we can work it out further.

Comment: I feel like on most sites this would just be an information overload. Perhaps if it had a filter option this might be useful. Just seeing what happens wouldn't necessarily be all that useful though in detecting items to moderate. /review feels like a more appropriate thing to look at.

Comment: @nhinkle: **`/review` falls short as it is based on heuristics**, I agree that it does help to identify Q&As of bad quality like [this example](http://superuser.com/questions/246803/internet-explorer-8-9-javascript-disable-need-to-enable-back/299404#299404). I doubt if the heuristics can or will ever help with the various close reasons or other reasons to edit or delete a post. If `/review` would help finding duplicates or filter off-topic, non-constructive, unreal and localized Q&As or edit non-detectable issues; this would be unnecessary... Filters are a great idea!

Comment: @TomWij you can also suggest new tabs for `/review` if you want.

Comment: @nhinkle: Well, we could house the tracker there, allowing us to review recent activity (showing questions & edits) and recent votes (showing close/reopen and [un]delete votes) or something along those lines. I'm just fantasizing, but I can see it as helpful so I'm going to await other thoughts...

Comment: You know about /tools, right? Because that shows you pretty much all of that information. Go take a look at http://superuser.com/tools/.

Comment: @nhinkle: Yes, see my second to last paragraph which mentions the `/tools` section.

Comment: I guess I don't personally feel like having one stream of everything that's happening would be useful to me, and I would prefer to have it summarized in `/tools`. However, if your moderation workflow would be aided by a tool like this, then that's great :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure what benefit there would be to this, or what indeed this wold show. Perhaps if you generated a dummy report for us to look at? Even better, ask about this on Stackapps. The data you mention is all publicly available.

Comment: I don't think there is a feed for close votes, is there?

Comment: @TomWij there is.

Comment: Sathya has pointed to me that these are available on the `/tools` page, perhaps I should stay around there for recent vote-related stuff and the front page for recent edit/answer stuff. It's only two tabs I need to keep open, and a third one could then be opened for the `/review` tab for things I seem to have skipped or when I was away. I would love to see it all combined but seems that requires some work that has a high cost for a low benefit...

Comment: [An extended chat discussion can be read here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/568/would-it-be-handy-to-have-a-live-activity-tracker-for-moderation-purposes), conclusion: It would be handy to have for me, but the costs out-weight the benefit and I'm not the only moderating user...

Answer (score 11):

Sorry this (IMO) is just way too much to digest - especially on high activity sites like Stack Overflow. I'd imagine this would inundate & overwhelm Moderators. The /tools route, Moderator dashboard, the constant stream of flags & auto flags by Community user are more than enough to keep an eye on thigs.

Comment: Remember that there are high reputation users, the moderators don't have to do the job alone. Of course Stack Overflow would have too much to handle, but on sites like Super User and others there really isn't too much...

Answer (score 10):

This sounds... Kinda insane. I mean, I'm all about information overload as a recreational drug, but... overdosing is no laughing matter. You could end up in a *Bing advertisement*!

We have a plethora of tools to help you (as a high-rep user) find problems. If you can identify a class of problems that don't show up, suggest another tool & we'll talk. But throwing *every action on the site* in your face... That's either sadism or masochism, depending on where you happen to stand. I can't in good conscience support it!

Comment: You can't put these in a tool with heuristics, they need to be watched either live or in a recent activity or votes tab. I'm not talking about every action but just those actions *that are interesting in the context of moderation*, and then you can still filter them out...

Comment: @TomWij: I'm just trying to imagine what this tool would look like on SO... I suppose it might be feasible to use such a thing on a smaller site, but even then... it seems almost designed to *waste the time* of whoever is unlucky enough to fall into it, which is just not something we want to do to our most active users.